# Is there a way to cleanly and easily undo a git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset, git-revert

I've read that doing git reset commitBeforeDoingMerge --hard would no undo the merge:

```
1pm-3pm This is my branch and I need to merge master into it
1pm-2pm This was master
1pm-2pm-3pm-4pm Merging ended up doing this, 4pm being the merge commit
1pm-2pm-3pm if This is the result if you do git reset 3pm --hard, because it does not undo the merge, it just goes back to that commit in the branch that was merged.
```

Now, another proposal is to do git revert 4pm -m 1, but that has a problem according to the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt---mainlineparent-number:%7E:text=Usually%20you%20cannot%20revert%20a%20merge,may%20not%20be%20what%20you%20want.):

> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side
> of the merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies
> the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert
> to reverse the change relative to the specified parent.
>
> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree
> changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only
> bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of
> the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.

So, is there a way to cleanly and easily undo a git merge?

Comment: `git reset --hard` will undo a merge. (always and cleanly) but I think you should clarify how you got your "merge" because a merge should have at least two parallel branches not your single line.

Comment: @ian I updated the question, maybe now it is more clear. Git reset --hard will take you to that snapshot but will not undo the changes made to the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you are doing, but this is not how `git merge` works. I will try to recreate what you did and maybe you can spot the difference.

First i created your two starting branches:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all
* 0593ba1 (HEAD -> test) 3pm
| * eba415c (master) 2pm
|/
* 7f9a804 1pm
```

Merging master into test.
`git merge master -m "4pm"`

```
git log --oneline --graph --all
*   6be609f (HEAD -> test) 4pm
|\
| * eba415c (master) 2pm
* | 0593ba1 3pm
|/
* 7f9a804 1pm
```

now we reset test back to 3pm

```
git reset --hard 0593ba1
HEAD is now at 0593ba1 3pm
```

```
git log --oneline --graph --all
* 0593ba1 (HEAD -> test) 3pm
| * eba415c (master) 2pm
|/
* 7f9a804 1pm
```

now we see the 2pm commit is only in master, to confirm the log of only test

```
git log --oneline
0593ba1 (HEAD -> test) 3pm
7f9a804 1pm
```

that is how I merge and undo the merge, please feel free to let me know what you are doing differently or where I have not recreated you example how you need it to be.

Comment: I think the confusion came to me when I mixed in my head undoing a merge that was pushed. So I tried to find a clean way to undo that without rewriting history.

Comment: no worry's, glad to be of help. If you really want to undo a merge without rewriting history you could do it with `git revert -m <#parent> <sha>`, but be careful to read up on this, because it has its own [pitfalls](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) and I'm not sure it is a better solution to rewriting history.

Answer (score 3):

> I've read that doing git reset commitBeforeDoingMerge --hard would no undo the merge

Wherever you read that, it is wrong. That is exactly how to undo a merge.

Let's say you are merging `branch` into `master`. So we have this before the merge:

```
A -- B -- C (master)
 \
  X -- Y (branch)
```

Okay, so we `git checkout master` and `git merge branch`. The result is:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (master)
 \             |
  X -- Y (branch)
```

...where D is the merge commit, with C and Y as its parents.

If you now say `git reset --hard <SHA-of-C>`, you are back to this:

```
A -- B -- C (master)
 \
  X -- Y (branch)
```

It is a perfect Undo.

Answer (score 1):

The reset should have worked, but on master, resetting to e:

After the merge:

```
a-b-d  (mybranch)
  \
   c-e (master)
```

A merge from `myBranch` to master should give:

```
a-b---d  (mybranch)
  \    \
   c-e-f (master)
```

There is no branch which would list abcdef, ony abcef (master)

If you `reset --hard e` while on `master` you would get back the original history (first one above)

If you `reset --hard d` while on master, you have move master HEAD but the merge still exists:

```
a-b---d  (mybranch, master)
  \    \
   c-e-f
```

Comment: I was merging master into my branch. I don't understand your answer so I updated the question, maybe it is more clear.