# Git: remove entire PR from code to test locally

Tags: git

I see a bug in the code repository, most likely coming from my colleague's PR. To confirm this I want to remove his suspect PR, rebuilt the code without it and see if that fixes the bug. His PR has about 10 commits, how can I remove all of his changes in that one PR from my local build and test please.

Comment: "PR" is not part of the git vocabulary. Did you meant "merge"? If so, a simple solution exists: locally revert the merge.
related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796878/is-there-a-way-to-cleanly-and-easily-undo-a-git-merge and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31697782/5470596

Comment: You can also check out a specific commit `git checkout <hash>` with `<hash>` replaced by the commit you want to go back to.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all 10 commits from your colleague's PR in your local repository, you can follow these steps:

**Firstly** Identify the branch which has done 10 commits by checking repository's pull requests section or remote branches.

**Secondly** just clarify which branches you want to revert for instance i name this branch as firstMileStone by this command

```
git checkout firstMileStone
```

**Thirdly** By `git log`you can find 10 commits made by your colleague memories or write it down it hashes

**Fourthly** after identifing 10 commits it's time to undo to get back before these changes by this command:

```
git revert <hash's commits>
```

**Lastly** rebuild the correct version and if you 100 percent sure about it, just simply push it to remote repository besides let your colleague know about bug new version for preventing any other mistake.