Revert a Git merge from develop branch
I have a feature branch called feature/shopsync that merged from develop branch today, then I do some commit in the feature/shopsync. Now I found the develop branch contains some unstable code, then I need to revert the merge. I have tried like this:
git log
git revert -m 1 <merge develop commit hash>

It seems did not revert the develop branch, when I using git status, nothing changed. Am I missing something?
This is what the commit log looks like:
commit 9a102a944b8ba96720af8f9ce8e6aa3d85335240
Merge: b9db6e2 35761a0e0
Author:Jiangxiaogiang <jiangxiaoqiang@vDl.C0M>
Mon Jun 17 11:02:29 2024 +0800Date:
Merge branch 'develop'of 192.168.116.91:learn/core-service into feature/shopsync

Incidentally, I am on the branch feature/shopsync right now.

Try following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64830251/6796856

You need to be on develop to run the revert command (if you want to revert the change from develop branch).

A revert creates a new commit that undoes the changes of a previous commit. Sounds to me like you're really looking to reset your branch prior to when you did the merge.

I only want to give up the merge commit , other commit are needed.

Maybe you used the wrong parent number for -m, have you tried -m 2?

If you did the revert command using commit ID 9a102a9, and if your feature branch before that merge commit was on b9db6e2, and develop was on 35761a0e0, then everything you did appears to be correct. How did you validate whether the revert actually happened? You said: "it seems did not revert the develop branch, when I using git status, nothing changed." Note that git status probably won't change after the revert, but git log will.

In Git, a branch is just a little "sticky note" pointing to a commit. You can literally look around in the .git/refs/heads and inspect the files there. There is nothing more to branches whatsoever, from the point of view of the Git data structures. This means issues with merging and branching are usually very easy to fix, thankfully.
Before the merge, your two branches looked like this:

develop -> commit 12345678
feature/shopsync -> commit abcdef1234

You then merged your current develop into feature/shopsync. This gave you a "merge commit" (which is special because it has two parent commits and not only one, but that's beside the point here). Now your situation is:

develop -> commit 12345678 (the same)
feature/shopsync -> commit 987654321 (the merge commit)

To put everything back to where it was before, you simply use the git branch command like so:
git checkout master    # or any other branch than feature/shopsync
git tag shopsync_backup feature/shopsync
git branch feature/shopsync abcdef1234 -f`
git checkout feature/shopsync

This makes the "sticky note" point back to the original commit. -f is required here because Git otherwise timidly refuses to overwrite that branch name. The initial git checkout is mentioned because you cannot overwrite a branch like this if it is currently checked out. It does not matter which other branch you check out, you just can't be on the one you're modifying. The git tag gives you a way back if you somehow mess up, it stores a tag (which is only a simple "sticky note" pointing to that commit as well) pointing to the currently "broken" commit of your feature branch).
To find your actual commit hashes, you can use git log --graph --decorate feature/shopsync develop which will show everything in a neat little colored graph - or use your favourite Git history browser in your IDE, if you have one.
This operation changes nothing in the Git history. If you keep track of the commit numbers, it is easy to do more shenanigans if you feel like it, or if you feel that something went wrong.
(N.B. it is helpful to have a completely clean working directory before doing these operations, if only for avoiding confusion. If in doubt, you can use git reset --hard to throw away anything you had going on (both changes you have added with git add but not committed yet; and un-added changes. git status will then tell you that there is nothing to do and everything is up to date. Obviously don't do that if you have uncommitted changes that you wish to keep around.)
You mentioned you did further commits in your feature branch after the merge. If you need those back, you can try to cherry-pick them:
git checkout feature/shopsync
git log --graph --decorate shopsync_backup
git cherry-pick 1a2b3c4d5e 213213abcabc ...

Again, you can get those logs with git log or your favourite IDE.

You can use this command to revert your git merge
git revert -m 1 
or the other work around will be checkout to the pervious commit and then force push the code to the branch you are working on so that the last commit disappers and then you can make yiur appropiate changes and then merge the branch
